# Discard handling a network request when a component unmounts

Tags: react-native, redux, es6-promise, fetch-api

Disclaimer: I know this answer has already been asked, *but* in my case I need a solution for a specific case that is not really covered by other questions/answers.

In my react-native application, I do a lot of network requests that may take a long time to complete. Each request is handled in two main ways:

- The request completed successfully. The global redux/flux state is updated and therefore the nested components are updated as well.
- The request throws an error. A network error, a server error, a `400` error, whatever. In this case a message must be displayed to the user, in the form of a message that appears on the screen or as an alert.

My problem is that when a component is unmounted, the fetch callbacks are processed anyway when the request completes. In the first case, this is not a problem: the store is updated successfully and everyone is happy.

In the second case though, it is a problem because:

- The alert would be displayed in a different screen, which is not correct and led to problems with the `Modal` component which I use to present error alerts.
- The appearance/disappearance of the error message is controlled by the component LOCAL state, which can not be updated on an unmounted component and therefore throws an error.

What are my possibile solutions here? The most trivial one would be to use in each component a `_isMounted` property and in each fetch error handler, don't do anything if `_isMounted == false`. However, this approach is verbose and an antipattern.

Do I have any other option?

Comment: Where are the fetch requests performed? Are the in the component or are they in the redux action?

Comment: The fetch requests are performed in a different file, but they are exposed to the component as a Promise in order to graphically handle the result

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-navigation` I believe you could deduct the state in actions and not call the alert.

My suggestion is that you pass the navigation prop to action method and deduct the navigation state there and call the alert as you require.